# Accessing a portion of a numpy array that increases in length

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, perceptron

```
for iter in range(0, max_iter):
    print("in loop")
    print(w[0:iter])
    print(X[0:iter])
```

I am currently attempting to access an increasing portion of a numpy array, the problem seems to be the first loop when accessing w[0:0], how else can I query this?

Currently, it outputs [] instead of the first value I was hoping for.

Comment: So, use `w[:iter + 1]`?

Comment: `for iter in range(1, max_iter+1):`?

Comment: Remember that in Python, the end of a range is always exclusive.  Thus, `x[0:0]` is always an empty list.  To see the first element, you need `x[0:1]`.